# Let $ f:(-1,1)\to(-1,1)$ be continuous, $f(x)=f(x^2)$ for every $x$ then the value of $f(\frac 1 4)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f:(-1,1)\to(-1,1)$ be continuous, $f(x)=f(x^2)$ for every $x$ and $f(0)=\frac 1 2$. Then $f(\frac 1 4)$ is $A)\frac{1}{16}\quad B)\frac{1}{4}\quad C)\frac{1}{2}\quad$ $D)$ can't be determined.

I don't know how to start with this problem? Please give me hints.

Comment: $f(1/4)=f(1/4^2)=f(1/4^{8})=...=f(1/4^{2^n})$. Take limits as $n\to \infty$ and use that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Well, a constant function is clearly an example of such a function, so we know that it must be either (C) or (D).

Comment: @AOlov Next time you could post something like this as answers instead in order to gain reputation for yourself instead of for others :)

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Others need it more than I do.

Comment: @AOlov I mean don't leave others the chance to snatch reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f\left(\cfrac{1}{4}\right) = f\left(\cfrac{1}{16}\right) = f\left(\cfrac{1}{256}\right) = f\left(\cfrac{1}{256^2}\right)=\dots$

Can you see where it is going?

$f\left(\cfrac 14\right) = f(0) = \cfrac 12$

Comment: I don't get the downvotes.

Comment: Probably people downvote this answer as it copies from the comment of AOlov

Comment: But this is the obvious answer, and since it isn't an exact copy, seems churlish to treat it as a copy. @AlexFrancisco

Comment: @ThomasAndrews This answer makes no essential improvement than AOlov's comment such as elaboration on the derivation. It simply paraphrases that comment, which should be discouraged.

Comment: Should i delete this answer?
This is the only approach for this question i guess

Comment: Kumar.All is well.You nicely presented it.+

Comment: The point of the site is to answer questions. Comments are not answers. A question without an answer cannot be closed as answers. Comments can be deleted over time. The point is to not just answer the OP, but to provide an answer for later readers. @AlexFrancisco